# Customize textview in android

Tags: android, textview

I want to customize my `textview` as per my requirement. I have to add `padding`  or `margin` dynamically when `text` is too long and it should look like my `screenshot` which I have attached here. Can anyone help me how can I implement it and below is my `screenshot`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. It is customizable. 
I used it so that I can have different color texts inside my "textview" , and also I used it, cause I did on it a code to resize the text size, so that it fits in the screen height. But if that was possible, I'm pretty sure what you want to do is also possible.
https://github.com/DavidPizarro/AutoLabelUI